# Look up Table dynamic searching for functionpointer or subtable at C

Tags: c, function-pointers, lookup-tables

I would have a method, that looks if a table or a functionpointer is in the table. Is it  a funktionpointer, the Method should be called. Is it a table, it should call the Method again and looks in the new table if it a funktionpointer or a table.
What have I must to chance, it should be looking dynamic.
the input (console with scanf). 
Structure from the hierarchy of a Table.
My tables are always Look up tables. But the Structure and the hierarchy are changed often.

Parser parsed the input from scanf in cmd1 and cmd2. Over cmd1 you can see " //first input " . Over cmd2 you can see "second input", because cmd1 is the first and cmd2 is the second input. I only want to know, who I can write my Method so, that anyone table with my struct can pointed to my Method find. And the Method find her way in the Table.Because every Table have an other hierarchy. The first don't have any subTables, the other have 6 subtables, the other have 9 subtables who have 5 subtables.

Example:

```
        > 1-> 1a,1b,1c :
        1a->2 : 2-> 2a,2b,2c -> 2a->MethodZZZ , 2b-> MethodQQ, 2c -> 2c1,2c2
        1b->MethodXX :
        1c-> 1c1,1c2,1c3 
        1c2-> MethodYY
```

```
    typedef struct Table
    {
        char* command;
        struct Table* subtab;
        void (*pfnFunction)(char*);
        char* description;
    } findTable;



     static void find(findTable* t , char* c)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int countHIT = 0;
// parser is a method to parsed the input from scanf in cmd1 and cmd2
            parser(cmd);

            //cmd1 is the first input
            if(cmd1 != NULL)
            {
                while(stricmp(t[i].command , "\0"))
                {//tosearch is the first char in my look up tables
                    if(check_Cmd( t[i].tosearch , cmd1) == 1)
                    {
                        //cmd2 is the second input 
                        if(cmd2 != NULL)
                        {
                        //when it has a subtab
                            if(t[i].subtab != NULL)
                            {
                                find(t[i].subtab , cmd2);
                            }

                            //when it has a funktionpointer
                            if(t[i].pfnFunction != NULL)
                            {
                                t[i].pfnFunction(cmd2);
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            printf("Error\n");
                            //Mehtod for a new input
                            Command();
                        }
                             //when the input isnt a funktionpointer or has a subtable, print the description
                            if(t[i].subtab == NULL && t[i].pfnFunction == NULL)
                            {
                                printf("Ausgabe: %s \n" , t[i].description);
                            }
                        countHIT = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                if(countHIT == 0)
                {
                    printf("Wrong input. \n");
                    Command();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("No input, please try again \n");
                findInput();
            }
        }

    static void findInput()
    {
        printf("Input: \n");
        fgets(input, 256 , stdin);
        input[strlen(input)-1] = '\0';
        find(head, input);
    //Head is the name of an Lookuptable
    }

    int main()
    {
       findInput();
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Show how you call `find`, show the definition of `findTable` and show the actual findtable.

Comment: What is `parser`, what is `cmd`, what is `cmd1`, what is `cmd2`, what is `check_Cmd`, what is that stray `second input` in your code ?? Be more explicit, otherwise your question will soon be closed.

Comment: parser parsed the input from scanf in cmd1 and cmd2. i have write it in my question. Over cmd1 you  can see " //first input " . Over cmd2 you can see "second input", because cmd1 is the first and cmd2 is the second input. i only would to know , who i can write my Method so, that anyone table with my struct can pointed to my Method find. And the Method find her way in the Table.Because every Table have an other heirachy. The first dont have any subTables, the other have 6 subtables, the other have 9 subtables who have 5 subtables.

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting a long comment.

Comment: okey, i have update my question